# SCP involving a grounded cargo ship

Tags: episode-identification, scp-foundation

I remember reading an [SCP](http://www.scp-wiki.net/) from a while ago that I wanted to look at again, but I can't seem to find it. Here's what I remember:

- Euclid class
- A cargo ship that has run aground
- Mobile Task Forces that enter never make it out
- Non Euclidean (rooms rearrange themselves)

Can anyone tell me which number this is?

Comment: What does SCP stand for?

Comment: The [SCP Foundation](http://www.scp-wiki.net/) is the multinational NGO that is tasked with securing, containing and protecting (us and them) various strange, weird and/or dangerous... *things...* that turn up around (and sometimes off) the world.

Comment: Possibly [SCP-455.](http://www.scp-wiki.net/scp-455)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### [SCP-455](http://www.scp-wiki.net/scp-455)

There's nothing about rooms rearranging themselves, but it's described as having interior dimensions and layout that don't match the exterior. Emphasis mine:

> SCP-455 is a large **cargo ship currently run aground** on the southern coast of Chile. Most of its structure is underwater and badly damaged, with rust coating 85 to 90 percent of all surfaces. **Internal structure appears to be significantly larger than external dimensions**, and is not flooded despite large holes visible on outer hull.
>
> Internal structure appears to be a random assembly of rooms, halls, and structures. Initial salvage teams reported rooms made of human teeth, an engine with tendon strips for timing belts, **a hall extending for 182.88 m (600 ft) beyond where the outer hull should terminate**, an open "gym" room with steel walls as pliant as taffy, and numerous audio and visual hallucinations. **Team was lost after reporting entry to "central navigation." Rescue team lost after reporting the investigation of "screaming" in a cargo section**.